# Is there a way to loop through a list in python?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I am trying to create a 2X2 table with the left side containing a list of the names of columns (from another dataframe) and the right side containing the sum of the integers in the rows of the corresponding columns.

The result of what I am trying to do would be something like this:

[image]

If you ask me, the coding sequence would look something like this:

- Store content in cell A1 in a string variable x;
- Go to dataframe, and find the column with that name;
- Sum said column and print the value in B1;
- Go one row down and x takes on the value of A2;
- Loop 6 times.

I tried using this code:

```
df.loc['Total',:]= df.sum(axis=0)
```

With the hope that once I get the total at the bottom, I would be able to create another column, transposed. But my python terminal hung anytime I ran that code (just 50,000 rows).

I also tried this

```
df['column name'].sum(axis=0)
```

But that only gave me the sum of one column. I have about 30 columns. And furthermore, I can only "Print" the codes. It doesn't put them in the table accordingly as would have been useful.
The end goal really is just the table. Anyway, suggestions or links to where it has been done before would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```py
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 0], "b":[5, 8, 1, 0, 3, 5], "c": [6, 2, 9, 9, 4, 2]})                                                   

In [4]: df                                                                      
Out[4]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  5  6
1  3  8  2
2  5  1  9
3  7  0  9
4  9  3  4
5  0  5  2

In [5]: df.sum()                                                                
Out[5]: 
a    25
b    22
c    32
dtype: int64
```

I'm a bit confused by the wording of your question. Is this the answer you want? Or do you want a method doing the same thing except using loops?

Comment: He's probably looking for something similar **df.sum().reset_index().rename({'index':'A', 0:'B'}, axis=1)**

Comment: Thanks Ryohei. I loop idea was from VB. I suggested it as my python kept crashing when I ran the codes I knew.

Tried using your code, and experienced the same problem.